# Modulo calculation with big numbers (C#)

Tags: c#

today in class we learned that a big modulo calculation can be divided into multiple smaller modulo calculations.

The example was `7^5 mod 11 (=10)` can be divided into `(((5^2) mod11)^2 mod11)*7 mod11`. That sounded understandable.

I built a method in C# and for the example and some other values it is working, but for most of the calculation results with other numbers (comparing to Wolfram Alpha) my code is wrong.

```
public static int moduloForBigNumbers(int baseValue, int exponent, int modulo)
        {
            int result;
            int newBase = baseValue;
            while (exponent > 1)
            {
                newBase = (int)Math.Pow(newBase, 2) % modulo;
                exponent = exponent - 2;
            }

            if (exponent == 1)
            {
                result = (newBase * baseValue) % modulo;
                return result;
            }
            return newBase; 
        }
```

For example when using 7, 560, 561 i get a wrong result. My first guesses were, that the numbers were too big, so i tried it with long. My 2nd guess is that something with the %-calculation is going wrong but i can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you checked with smaller numbers as well? I.e. you mention big numbers as if this is causing the bug but have you verified this?

Comment: What is your expected value, and what is the actual value?

Comment: No i don't find the reason why it is acting up. It is also happening with smaller numbers.